# Two users having same role, profile and permissions, but one user is not able to see certain field

Tags: lightning, profile, permission-sets

Two users having same role, profile and permissions, but one user is not able to see a field, which can be seen by other user.

Comment: can you check the extra permission set assigned or not to the other user who is having field access?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is because one of the user has a permission set or permission Set Group Assigned while the other does not
2. Kindly assign the same permission set or permission set Group to the other user who is not able to access the field or else create a new permission set or permission set Group for the user and assign it (completely upto your business requirement)